# dynamically render a blazor component next to App component

Tags: components, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Is it possible to render a Blazor component dynamically next to App component? It may be crazy, but I have a requirement where I have to render a component dynamically next to the top of the Blazor App or body element.

```
<app>
   // Here my Blazor component needs to be rendered dynamically.
   // Rest of the other components rendering in a regular manner.
</app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming when you say dynamically means you have different components to render in different scenarios. If this is the requirement then you can use if else conditions. You can use variables which represents your scenario#(s) in if condition.

Example:

```
<app>
@if(scenario#1){
<Component1/>
}
else if (scenario#2)
{
<Component2/>
}
else{
<Component3/>
}
</app>
```